# Check if user is logged in Laravel sanctum with Vuejs SPA

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to solve this but I can't, I have a website built with Laravel and Vuejs:
This is my app.js

```
import 'bootstrap';
import './axios';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import store from './store';
import router from './router';

store.dispatch('checkAuth');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store ,
    router
});
```

this is my router.js:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Register from './components/Register';
import Main from './components/Main';   

   const checkLogin = (to, from, next) =>{
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {    
    if (!store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
      next({name: 'login' })
    } else {
      next()
    }

  } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresVisitor)) {
    if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
      next({name: 'home' })
    } else {
      next()
    }

  } else {
    next()
  }

}   

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', 
      beforeEnter: checkLogin,          
      component: Main,
      meta: { requiresAuth: true },       
      children : [
        {
          path: "",
          name: "home",
          component: PostsList
        },
        ....      

      ] 
    },    
    { 
        path: '/login', 
        beforeEnter: checkLogin,
        component: Login, 
        name:'login',
        meta: { requiresVisitor: true } 
    },
    { 
        path: '/register',
        beforeEnter: checkLogin, 
        component: Register, 
        name: 'register',
        meta: { requiresVisitor: true }  
    }    

  ]
});
```

and this is my store:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
const state = {  
  user: null,
  isAuthenticated: false
};

const getters = {  
  isAuthenticated(state){
      return state.isAuthenticated;
  },
  currentUser(state){
      return state.user;
  }
};

  async login({commit, dispatch}, credentials) {  
    await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');    
    const {data} = await axios.post("/login", credentials);
    commit('setAuth', data);           
  },

  async checkAuth({commit}) {  
      const {data} = await axios.get('/api/user');    
      commit('setAuth', data);               
  }
}

const mutations = {  
  setAuth(state, payload) {    
    state.user = payload.user;
    state.isAuthenticated = Boolean(payload.user);            
  }    
};
```

Then the problem arrives when I refresh the page, it calls the action:

**store.dispatch('checkAuth');**

then it should wait until the action is done because I did this in the action:

**const {data} = await axios.get('/api/user');**

But no, it doesn't wait because vue-router is executed and as the user state is not set yet , **store.getters.isAuthenticated is false** then it redirects to /login, then when I check the vue tools in the browser and see that the state was set correctly even the request to api/user returns the user correctly, Because before that I logged in a user, I need that vue-router waits until the vuex state is set. what can I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem, but I don't know if this is the best way to do it:

in my app.js
Instead of this:

```
store.dispatch('checkAuth');
    
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        store ,
        router
    });
```

I did this:

```
const VueInstance = ()=>{
  new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            store ,
            router
        });
}

store.dispatch('checkAuth').then(()=>{
    VueInstance();
}).catch(()=>{
    VueInstance();
});
```

Now it is working because the vuex action **checkAuth** returns a promise, so I needed to wait until it is completed, but, in case the action returns an error, because in the first load the user is not logged in, I must add a **catch**, because th Vue should be created whether the user is logged in or not. If someone have a better solution let me know. Thank you.