# Infinity Preloader AdminLTE3 VueJS and laravel-sanctum

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, laravel-sanctum

I using:
VueJS 2
Laravel 8
Larvel Sanctum
Laravel Mix
and want to check auth before enter to page
[I used this answer for realease auth check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832674/check-if-user-is-logged-in-laravel-sanctum-with-vuejs-spa), but with AdminLTE3 Preloader preloader freeze and site doesn't loading
Vuex store:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        user: false,
        isCheckedAuth: false
    },
    mutations:{
        auth(state, payload){
            state.user=payload;
            state.isCheckedAuth = true;
        }
    },
    getters:{
        isAuth(state){
            if(!state.user) return false; else return true;
        },
        getNameInitials(state){
            return `${state.user.last_name} ${state.user.first_name[0]}. ${state.user.middle_name[0]}.`;
        },
        hasPermission(state){
            return function (needPermission){
                if(state.user.permissions.find(permission => permission === needPermission))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        },
        isCheckedAuth(state){
            return state.isCheckedAuth;
        }
    },
    actions:{
        async checkAuth(){
            return await axios.get('/api/v.1.0/user').then(r=>{
                store.commit('auth',r.data.data)
            })
        }
    }
})
```

VueInstance:

```js
const VueInstance = ()=>{
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        router,
        store,
        components: { App }
    })
}
store.dispatch('checkAuth').then(() => {
    VueInstance();
}).catch(() => {
    VueInstance();
})
```

if i change to

```js
new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        router,
        store,
        components: { App }
    })
```

, it's working but I can't check auth before enter page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something else. I add to Vuex property isCheckerAuth and add watchers to component that need to check auth. Also I have mounted method and on it check isChecked true or false
in Vuex:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        user: false,
        isCheckedAuth: false
    },
    getters:{
        isAuth(state){
            if(!state.user) return false; else return true;
        },
        isCheckedAuth(state){
            return state.isCheckedAuth;
        },
    }
})
```

in component:

```html
<template>
    <!--you need to add some loading screen when isLoading-->
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isLoading: true
        }
    },
    watch:{
        "$store.getters.isCheckedAuth"(){
            if(this.$store.getters.isAuth)
                this.isLoading = false;
            else
                this.$router.push({name:'home'});
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        if(this.$store.getters.isCheckedAuth&&(!this.$store.getters.isAuth)
            this.$router.push({name:'home'});
        else if(this.$store.getters.isCheckedAuth)
            this.isLoading = false
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```